# ¿Cual es el orden apropiado para un substantivo con adjetivo y/o participio + "de"?

Tags: sintaxis

Se trata, por ejemplo, de un paciente que saldrá del hopital donde fue curado de una enfermedad. El hospital ha sido recientemente abierto, y el paciente es satisfecho.

En este caso, ¿cuáles son las combinaciones correctas y/o posibles? ¿Son posibles en castellano todas esas combinaciones?

1. Mañana el paciente, restablecido y satisfecho, saldrá del hospital recientemente inaugurado.
2. El restablecido paciente satisfecho saldrá del recientemente inaugurado hospital.
3. El paciente, restablecido y satisfecho, saldrá del hospital recientemente inaugurado.
4. El restablecido paciente saldrá del recientemente establecido hospital satisfecho.
5. El restablecido paciente del hospital recientemente inaugurado saldrá de allí satisfecho.
6. El restablecido paciente del recientemente inaugurado hospital saldrá de allí mañana satisfecho. O ¿mañana saldrá de allí satisfecho?
7. El satisfecho paciente restablecido del (o ¿en el?) hospital recientemente inaugurado saldrá de allí.
8. Mañana el paciente restablecido y satisfecho/(satisfecho y restablecido) del recientemente inaugurado hospital saldrá de allí, etc.

Ya no sé cuales son las frases posibles, y cuales son erróneas. ¡Que me ayuden con la sintaxis, por favor!

Y una pregunta más: ¿no digan ´el paciente quitará el hospital´ en lugar de "saldrá del hospital"?

Comment: 1 o 3 (no olvidaste "mañana" en la 3?) están bien. 2 4 7 son las peores, casi ilegibles. Contribuye este detalle incómodo: "paciente" es sustantivo pero también puede ser adjetivo; entonces, una expresión como "restablecido paciente satisfecho" resulta muy confusa.

Comment: ´Mañana´ no es un detalle obligatorio.

Comment: También, ten en cuenta que «y/o» es un anglicismo inecesario en español, basta con solo «o».

Answer (score 1):

La opción 3 es la que mejor suena:

> El paciente, curado y contento, saldrá del hospital recientemente establecido.

La opción 1 es válida tambien.

Normalmente se pone el adjetivo después del nombre, de manera que, por regla general, debes preferir *"paciente curado"* a *"curado paciente"*, excepto en canciones y textos poéticos.

En otro orden de cosas, un hospital no se *'establece'* sino que *'abre'* o *'se inaugura'*. Además, quizás *'contento'* y *'curado'* no sean las mejores palabras que puedas usar:

> El paciente, restablecido y satisfecho, saldrá del hospital recientemente inaugurado.

Esto sería algo formal, propio de una noticia en el periódico o del folleto publicitario del nuevo hospital, o, en un lenguaje menos formal, se puede decir:

> Pablito, curado y contento, saldrá del hospital que han abierto hace poco.

Y, por último, *'quitar'* en español significa eliminar o suprimir. No tiene ningún significado parecido al inglés *'To quit'* o al francés *'Quitter'*, como pareces sugerir. Sin embargo, sí se puede usar *'dejar'* o *'abandonar'*.

> El paciente, ya restablecido, dejará el hospital mañana.

Puede serte útil conocer la expresión técnica *'dar de alta'* que se refiere al acto de que el médico declare que el paciente esta curado o, al menos ,que no es preciso que continúe en el hospital para su restablecimiento, pudiendo continuarlo en su casa o siguiendo una cierta medicación.

> El paciente, ya restablecido, será dado de alta mañana.
>
> Mañana darán de alta a Pablito del nuevo hospital

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: ¡Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Para mi todas las opciones son viables con las comas adecuadas:

> Mañana el paciente, restablecido y satisfecho, saldrá del hospital recientamente inaugurado.
>
> El restablecido paciente, satisfecho, saldrá del recientamente inaugurado hospital.
>
> El paciente, restablecido y satisfecho, saldrá del hospital recientamente inaugurado.
>
> El restablecido paciente, saldrá del recientamente establecido hospital, satisfecho.
>
> El restablecido paciente del hospital recientamente inaugurado, saldrá de allí satisfecho.
>
> El restablecido paciente, del recientamente inaugurado hospital, saldrá de allí satisfecho mañana.
>
> El satisfecho paciente, restablecido en el hospital recientamente inaugurado, saldrá de allí.
>
> Mañana el paciente, restablecido y satisfecho del recientamente inaugurado hospital, saldrá de allí.